# Android Arraylist Baseadapter button click Create new Arraylist with no duplicacy

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

I have a  custom listview base adapter in which we have add cart and buttons in each row when click on add cart button it call interface function

```
    HeadingRowItem headingRowItem = (HeadingRowItem)rowItems.get(pos);
    addRowItem= new AddRowItem(headingRowItem.getTitle(),headingRowItem.getQty(),headingRowItem.getTotalqty(),headingRowItem.getPrices(),headingRowItem.getTotalprice());
    Log.d("myvalueb",""+data.size());
    data.add(addRowItem);
```

it working fine but it creates duplicacy so how to avoid duplicacy if using 
data.set(pos,addRowItem); it give me arrayindexoutofbound exception.

Thanks

Comment: Use Hashset to remove the duplicate. Refer the link : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashset

Comment: Hi , but how to send hashset one fragment to other fragment as my arraylist is parciable and on other fragment will receive it and put in adapter . so can i make it serializable or what any example ?

Comment: convert  Hahset again to the Arraylist of your type

Comment: when convert again in arraylist it make again duplicate .. so again hang on same issue ..HeadingRowItem headingRowItem = (HeadingRowItem)rowItems.get(pos);
        addRowItem= new AddRowItem(headingRowItem.getTitle(),headingRowItem.getQty(),headingRowItem.getTotalqty(),headingRowItem.getPrices(),headingRowItem.getTotalprice());
      //  Log.d("myvalueb",""+data.size());
        data1.add(addRowItem);
        data = new ArrayList<AddRowItem>(data1);

Comment: Now Get solution before sending in other fragment I have use this loop
                for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
                    for(int j=i+1;j<data.size();j++){
                        if(data.get(i).getTitle().equals(data.get(j).getTitle())){
                            data.remove(i);
                            j--;
                        }
                    }
                } so can avoid duplicacy ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good solution to avoid duplicate data

```
            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){//

                for(int j=i+1;j<data.size();j++){//
                    if(data.get(i).getTitle().equals(data.get(j).getTitle())){
                        data.remove(i);
                        j--;
                    }
                }
            }
```

before sending in other fragment it works and make a new adapter in other fragment for this data .. 
Thanks to All..

Answer (score 1):

You facing **[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)**

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

For ***Duplicate*** issue You should use **[HashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html)**

> Main difference between ArrayList and HashSet is that ArrayList
>   allow duplicates while HashSet doesn't allow duplicates.

- If you try to add a duplicate element in **HashSet**, the old value would
  be overwritten.

Comment: Hi , but how to send hashset one fragment to other fragment as my arraylist is parciable and on other fragment will receive it and put in adapter . so can i make it serializable or what any example ?

Comment: @Vishal same process

Answer (score 0):

try below code and this Gradle in your build.gradle `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'` and `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'`

```
HashSet<AddRowItem> data = new HashSet<>();
data.add(addRowItem);

//add bundle
String details = new Gson().toJson(data);
Fragment homeFragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction homeTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("details", details);
homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
homeTransaction.addToBackStack("YourFragment");
homeTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, homeFragment, "YourFragment");
homeTransaction.commit();
```

another fragment on createView method add below code

```
View onCreateView(){
        Bundle mBundle = getArguments();
        if (mBundle != null) {
            String details = mBundle.getString("details");
            HashSet<AddRowItem> data = new Gson().fromJson(details, HashSet.class);

        }
}
```

Comment: Hi , but how to send hashset one fragment to other fragment as my arraylist is parciable and on other fragment will receive it and put in adapter . so can i  make it serializable or what any example ?